# Combining Streams of substrings

Tags: java, substring, java-stream

I have the following code that iterates over Java `DateTimeFormatter` pattern combinations of `"E".."EEEE"` and `"M".."MMMM"`.

My question is, is there an idiomatic (or just 'more idiomatic') way to use Java Streams in this case?

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class DateTimeFormattingStackOverflow {
    static LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    static Stream<String> substrings(String str) {
        return IntStream.range(1, str.length() + 1)
                .mapToObj(i -> str.substring(0, i));
    }

    static void printDateTime(String pattern) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        System.out.println(pattern + ", " + dtf.format(dateTime));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<String> patterns = substrings("EEEE")
                .flatMap(e -> substrings("MMMM").map(m -> e + " " + m))
                .map(em -> em + " d");

        patterns.forEach(DateTimeFormattingStackOverflow::printDateTime);
    }
}
```

Output

```
E M d, Sat 7 1
E MM d, Sat 07 1
E MMM d, Sat Jul 1
E MMMM d, Sat July 1
EE M d, Sat 7 1
EE MM d, Sat 07 1
EE MMM d, Sat Jul 1
EE MMMM d, Sat July 1
...
```

Comment: Do you need it to be with streams or can it be another *idiomatic* way?

Comment: I was particularly interested in trying to do this in 'a Streams way', but you are correct that non-Stream versions of this code could be equally/more idiomatic Java, and I thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `IntStream` to *drive* the string. That's one way to do it, and here are two other ways:

```
static Stream<String> substrings(String str) {
    return str.length() == 1 ? Stream.of(str) :
            Stream.concat(Stream.of(str), substrings(str.substring(1)));
}
```

This creates a `Stream` recursively, while the other way would be as follows:

```
static Stream<String> substrings2(String str) {
    return Stream.iterate(str, s -> s.substring(1)).limit(str.length());
}
```

This applies the given function to the previous result. As it creates an infinite stream, you have to use `limit`.

I have slightly modified your `main` method, so that you avoid one `map` operation:

```
substrings("EEEE")
    .flatMap(e -> substrings("MMMM").map(m -> e + " " + m + " d"))
    .forEach(DateTimeFormattingStackOverflow::printDateTime);
```

---

I really don't know if the ways above are more or less idiomatic than your way, but if you ask me, the most idiomatic way to do this task is with a nested loop:

```
String e = "EEEE";
String m = "MMMM";

for (int i = 0; i < e.length(); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m.length(); j++)
        printDateTime(e.substring(i) + " " + m.substring(j) + " d");
```

And this might be translated to Java 8 as follows:

```
IntStream.range(0, e.length()).boxed()
    .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, m.length())
        .mapToObj(j -> e.substring(i) + " " + m.substring(j) + " d"))
    .forEach(DateTimeFormattingStackOverflow::printDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the way in which you generate repeated runs of a character: rather than constructing the longest string manually, and then iterating its prefixes, I would construct runs with `Collection.nCopies`, like this:

```
static Stream<String> repeatedRuns(String c, int start, int end) {
    return IntStream
        .rangeClosed(start, end)
        .mapToObj(len -> 
            Collections.nCopies(len, c).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(""))
        );
}
```

You would then replace `substrings("EEEE")` with `repeatedRuns("E", 1, 4)`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/0lRs7s)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is more idiomatic, but I would squeeze that to a single method (it could be just me...)

```
 public static Stream<String> combinations(String first, String second, String d, LocalDateTime dateTime) {

        Stream<String> s = IntStream.range(0, first.length())
                .mapToObj(i -> first.substring(0, i + 1))
                .flatMap(x -> IntStream.range(0, second.length())
                        .mapToObj(i -> second.substring(0, i + 1))
                        .map(m -> String.join(" ", x, m))
                        .map(res -> res + " d")
                        .peek(System.out::print)
                        .map(DateTimeFormatter::ofPattern)
                        .map(dtf -> dtf.format(dateTime)));
        return s;
    }

   combinations("EEEE", "MMMM", " d", LocalDateTime.now()).forEach(x -> System.out.println(", " + x));
```

Comment: I don’t consider `String.join(" ", x, m)` to be better than just `x+" "+m`, but whatever style you prefer, it’s inconsistent to use the other right in the next line with `.map(res -> res + " d")`. Especially as you could do that in one operation, `String.join(" ", x, m, "d")` or `x+" "+m+" d"`…

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t stream over substrings at all. It’s enough to stream over something representing the sixteen combinations and to construct the format string in one operation:

```
Stream<String> patterns = IntStream.range(0, 16).map(i -> 15-i)
    .mapToObj(i -> "EEEE".substring(i>>2)+" "+"MMMM".substring(i&3)+" d");
```

The fact that these are four times four combinations makes the calculation eligible for cheap bit arithmetic, but in principle, any *n*×*m* combination is possible by streaming from 0 to *n*×*m* and using `i/n` and `i%n` for selecting the element (like performing the `substring` operation). The preceding `.map(i -> 15-i)` step just reverses the order to match it with your original code; you can omit it if the order doesn’t matter.